# Why javascript code is not working on Microsoft Edge, IE, UC(on mobile), Opera MIni(on mobile), working in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a form with two radio buttons(Type: Response & Application), based upon the selection it shows/hides addition part. Code is working on few of the browser.
Thank you in advance!

This is a form code:

```html
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
                            <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
                                <label class="w3-col l3 m3 s12" for="email">Email<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label>
                                <div class="w3-col l8 m9 s12">
                                    <input type="email" class="w3-input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email ID" required autofocus>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
                                <label class="w3-col l3 m3 s12" for="pwd">Contact<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label>
                                <div class="w3-col l8 m9 s12">
                                    <input type="tel" class="w3-input" id="cont" name="contact" placeholder="Enter your Contact number" minlength="10" maxlength="10"required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
                                <label class="w3-col l3 m3 s12" for="pwd">Messege<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label>
                                <div class="w3-col l8 m9 s12">
                                    <textarea class="w3-input" id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="3" cols="3" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="w3-row w3-padding">
                                <label class="w3-col l3 m3 s12">Type<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label>
                                <div class="w3-col l8 m9 s12 w3-row" style="padding-left: 18px"> 
                                    <input type="radio" name="type1" value="Response" class="w3-radio" id="type2" onclick="document.getElementById('applicationfor').style.display ='none';" checked="" required>Response
                                    <input type="radio" name="type1" value="Application" class="w3-radio" id="type3" onclick="document.getElementById('applicationfor').style='visibility: visible';" required>Application
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                
                            <div class="w3-row w3-padding" style="display: none" id="applicationfor">
                                <label class="w3-col l3 m3 s12">Applying for:</label>
                                <div class="w3-col l8 m9 s12">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <label>set 1<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label><br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set1" value="Subtitle" class="w3-radio" id="r1"> Subtitle Creator (English)<br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set1" value="EngLyr" class="w3-radio" id="r2"> Lyrics Writing (English)<br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set1" value="Set1None" class="w3-radio" id="r3"> None<br/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <label>set 2<span class="w3-text-red w3-large">*</span>:</label><br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set2" value="HinSub" class="w3-radio"> Subtitle Creator (Hindi)<br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set2" value="HinLyr" class="w3-radio"> Lyrics Writing (Hindi)<br/>
                                            <input type="radio" name="set2" value="Set2None" id="set2val" class="w3-radio"> None<br/>
                                        </li>
                                        <h4 style="color: #FF0000" id="raderror"></h4>
                                        <h4 style="color: #FF0000" id="raderror2"></h4>
                                        
                                        <li>
                                            <label>Additional Message:</label>
                                            <textarea name="additionalmsg" class="w3-input" placeholder="Additional message(optional)" rows="3" cols="8"></textarea>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="s3 w3-large w3-padding-16 w3-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green w3-hover-text-black">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. Read it from our point of view: *Why is this code, which I am not going to show you, only works in some browsers?* How in the world do you expect us to know why code we cannot see doesn't work for you?

Comment: Post relevant portions of your code so we have something to work with...

Comment: Dude, I am new here. I was not aware how to add code, as i was trying to type code, it start executing the code

Comment: @Marvin, JJJ, Thomasz and VDWWD   Thank you for your support. I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code we will not be able to identify your problem. But Different browsers render and act differently in some situation. if you use jQuery like library it will be easy to get done what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=type1]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'Response') {//if the value of radio button is male
            //your code to show the other part
            $("#Responsediv").show();
            $("#Applicationdiv").hide();


        }
        else if (this.value == 'Application') {//if the value of radio button is female
            //your code to show the other part
            $("#Responsediv").hide();
            $("#Applicationdiv").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using simple javascript. But I don't mind using jQuery or js

Comment: then try this. This should work

Comment: Will let you know today (4 July afternoon)

Comment: ok also please make sure you accept the answer if this is correct

Comment: It;s working fine now. Above code is well sufficient. Thank You @pavithra

Comment: happy to help man